# difference in AppNexus and Admelds business area?

Tags: ads, advertisement-server

Are AppNexus and Admeld competitors?
Do they overlap in business? If no, what are the differences?
What are their strong suits in advertising?

Answer (score 2):

AppNexus and Admeld are very different animals.  AppNexus is a demand-side-platform whereas Admeld is a supply-side-platform.  While they both have inventory to sell, AppNexus focussed on maximizing performance and cost on behalf of the advertisers and supply-side-platforms optimize bids to increase revenue for publishers.  They both plug in to each other but their technology stack and the way both of them are marketed is very different.

Check out this graphic to get a better understanding of the space: http://www.glennengler.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/LUMA-Landscape2010-12-12.jpg

-Justin Kline